# Adding server side rendering to an existing React app

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to build a react app starter that suits my needs. I've read, downloaded, tested countless react boilerplate to try to understand how to add SSR but I'm kind of stuck right now.

[The github repo is here](https://github.com/gregory-latinier/react-app-starter)

So far I've got React running with hot reload. Webpack 4 bundles the client code. I use a proxy with webpack-dev-server (WDS) to serve my backend express api as well as my client for development. 
WDS hot reload change when I update app client code. The express server doesn't restart that  way.
I use nodemon to watch the change of the server so that only the backend restarts when I'm coding api features.

For production I simply build the server and client to the dist folder and serve the application with node.

Later I plan to add React router, redux, etc but this is the easy part.

So what I'd like to add now is server side rendering (SSR) for the production mode as I don't need it for development.

Any idea on how I could implement that ?

Thank you

Comment: It might be worth looking into [Razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle).

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately your question is very broad and hard to answer in a length that would be reasonable for this platform. Try to start implementing what you want to achieve and narrow your questions down to something more specific when you struggle.

Comment: That's why I added the link to the github repo to have a precise example to provide a code snippet instead of a generic answer not based on actual code

Comment: I see but your questions is about how to implement SSR which is involving a lot of different steps and is well explained in tutorials out there. Therefore the question as it is is not suitable for stack overflow. Maybe you can narrow it down to a specific programming aspect of ssr? Giving us your app and asking for how to implement XY with it will not result in useful answers I'm afraid.

Comment: I did look at the Razzle framework but want to avoid the use of framework. I also looked at NextJS, Gatsby, ...

Comment: If I start a pull request with what I've come up so far it would be better for stackoverflow ?

Comment: I'd suggest to find one or two good tutorials (there are plenty) about SSR and follow them. Then try to apply that on your own app and if you struggle at a specific point you can ask here including the relevant code embedded into the question (links github repos can become unavailable making the question less useful). Also see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a further analysis.

Right now I start a webpack-dev-server that allows me to serve and hot reload the client app on localhost:3000
I also launch an express server on localhost:8080 and connect it to the client using the `proxy` attribute of the `devServer`

If I modify code on the client app only the hot reload is triggered
If I modify code on the express api only the server api is restarted

From what I understand of SSR and hot reload being put together is that webpack now needs to be compiled in the express server and I add a dev server and a hot reload middleware.

But if I do that each time I modify code of the api nodemon will restart the server and then webpack will compile the client code but I don't need that since I only modified the api.

What I think I need to do is leave things as they are for the development part (because I don't need SSR for dev) but add a production code that will be executed only if `NODE_ENV=production`, add a template dedicated to serve the html for production with all the `renderToString` logic

How's that sound ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons). It has Webpack 4, router, redux, and more all working with SSR. Plus it has both development and production modes.